# Display the number of iteration in the input box of excel vba for every iteration

Tags: excel, vba, loops, message, user-input

I have to display the input box with a message having the number of iteration in it. Please help.

Eg:I need the input box to display the message as "Please input Name: 1" for first iteration then
"Please input Name: 2" for second iteration and so on depending on the number of iterations.

Appreciate an early reply..
Thanks,
Learner_VBA

Comment: Please show some work you have done so far, so we can help you better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the following:

```
For i = start to limit

Input = InputBox("Please input name:" & i)

'Rest of code here
'
'
'
next i
```

Just curious, but how many iterations are you looking at?

Comment: About 10-20 iterations. Thanks a lot... Ash

Comment: Hmm, 10-20 might be a bit tedious to enter into an input box each time, 

Try seeing if you could enter all the data in one shot in a worksheet and then iterate through it from your loop.